# data.table reference semantics: memory usage of iterating through all columns

Tags: r, data.table, pass-by-reference

When iterating through all columns in an R data.table using reference semantics, what makes more sense from a memory usage standpoint:

(1) `dt[, (all_cols) := lapply(.SD, my_fun)]`

or

(2) `lapply(colnames(dt), function(col) dt[, (col) := my_fun(dt[[col]])])[[1]]`

My question is: In (2), I am forcing data.table to overwrite `dt` on a column by column basis, so I would assume to need extra memory on the order of column size. Is this also the case for (1)? Or is all of `lapply(.SD, my_fun)` evaluated before the original columns are overwritten?

Some sample code to run the above variants:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a = 1:10, b = 11:20)
my_fun <- function(x) x + 1
all_cols <- colnames(dt)
```

Comment: off the top of my head, if you have optimization on, internally (1) will be converted to `.(my_fun(.SD[[1]]), ..., my_fun(.SD[[ncol(.SD)]]))`; try running with `verbose = TRUE` and see `?GForce`

Comment: also if you're going to loop like in (2), you're better off using `set`; see `? set`

Comment: @MichaelChirico That optimization is for `j = .(...)` but not yet for `:=` https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1414 so I guess a `for` + `set` loop is best to minimize memory usage, as you suggested.

Comment: @MichaelChirico could you please elaborate a bit on how my question is related to `GForce`? As per the docs (v1.11.4), this is only concerned with the case where `my_fun` is in {`min`, `max`, `mean`, `median`, `var`, `sd`, `sum`, `prod`, `first`, `last`, `head`, `tail`}, but not for an arbitrary `my_fun`, right?

Comment: See optimization level 1: "The expression `DT[, lapply(.SD, fun), by=.]` gets optimised to `DT[, list(fun(a), fun(b), ...), by=.] `where `a,b, ...` are columns in `.SD`. This improves performance tremendously."

Comment: Ah, ok, you were using `?GForce` synonymous with `? datatable.optimize` but not referring to the level 2 optimizations specifically. My bad.

Comment: @Frank, do you agree with what I'm saying in my answer?

Comment: Yes, though I'm not sure if optimization to the `list(...)` form actually saves memory (by calculating and assigning each column separately) since I don't know the internals that well, though @MichaelChirico seems to be suggesting that it does (?). An alternative would be to melt the data to long form, something like `melt(dt[, r := .I], id="r")[, my_fun(value), by=variable]` ... also, it looks like lapply optimization os not used in when there is no `by=`. (For example, `DT[, lapply(.SD, sqrt), verbose=TRUE]` vs `DT[, lapply(.SD, sqrt), by=b, verbose=TRUE]`)

Comment: yes, i could have been more clear -- I should have sent you to `?datatable.optimize` but I couldn't remember the exact name (on mobile so couldn't test)

Comment: No problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the suggestion of @Frank, the most efficient way (from a memory point of view) to replace a data.table column by column by applying a function `my_fun` to each column, is

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a = 1:10, b = 11:20)
my_fun <- function(x) x + 1
all_cols <- colnames(dt)

for (col in all_cols) set(dt, j = col, value = my_fun(dt[[col]]))
```

This currently (v1.11.4) is not handled in the same way as an expression like `dt[, lapply(.SD, my_fun)]` which internally is optimised to `dt[, list(fun(a), fun(b), ...)]`, where `a, b, ...` are columns in `.SD` (see `?datatable.optimize`). This might change in the future and is being tracked by [#1414](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1414).