# data.table reference semantics: internals of iterating through columns and row groups

Tags: r, data.table, pass-by-reference

This questions is similar to

[data.table reference semantics: memory usage of iterating through all columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52189712/data-table-reference-semantics-memory-usage-of-iterating-through-all-columns)

but discusses a slightly different setting, so I decided on keeping them separate.

When replacing all columns in a data.table by applying a function `my_fun` to each column, in combination with grouping rows using the `by` argument, what roughly happens in a setting like

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a = 1L:10L, b = 11L:20L, c = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 5))
my_fun <- function(x) x + 1L

dt[, c("a", "b") := lapply(.SD, my_fun), by = "c", .SDcols = c("a", "b")]
```

(1) The problem is first split into groups and for each group `lapply(.SD, my_fun)` is evaluated. Before moving to the next group, the results are written to `dt`. As per [the referenced question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52189712/data-table-reference-semantics-memory-usage-of-iterating-through-all-columns), the memory overhead in this case is approx max(n_rows per group) x (n_cols in `.SD`) x  sizeof(data_type)

(2) The problem is split into groups and for each group `lapply(.SD, my_fun)` is evaluated. When done with iterating over all groups, the result is written to the respective columns in `dt`. In this case, the memory overhead is approx (n_rows in `dt`) x (n_cols in `.SD`) x  sizeof(data_type)

(3) The problem is approached in a column by column manner and for each column, the column is split and `my_fun` is called on each subset of the current column. When done with the complete column, results are written to `dt`. This would incur an approx mem overhead of (n_rows in `dt`) x  sizeof(data_type).

(4) Something else?

From the answer in [the question referenced above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52189712/data-table-reference-semantics-memory-usage-of-iterating-through-all-columns), (3) could be enabled in the future via an optimization similar to that outlined in `?datatable.optimize` in the level 1 section, but currently (v1.11.4) is not available.

The reason why I'm asking this question, is that especially if in setting (2) and in some cases maybe also in setting (1), it could make sense to somehow force a column by column approach.

Unfortunately, in the following does not work as `set()` does not support grouping.

```
for (col in c("a", "b")) set(dt, j = col, value = my_fun(dt[[col]]), by = "c")
```

Also, something like

```
lapply(c("a", "b"), function(col) dt[, (col) := my_fun(dt[[col]]), by = "c"])
```

does not work, as the nested subsetted `dt[[col]]` is not partitioned. Is there another way to achieve what I'm trying to, using `data.table`?

Answer (score 0):

I now think that (1) most accurately describes how columns are updated in grouped fashion. I come to this conclusion from the following observation: If updating columns by reference using a `by` argument, the new data type has to match the old one. This is not the case when updating an entire column by reference.

In order to force the column by column approach, I guess one could do the row-group subsetting manually and have a nested double loop: one iterating over columns and one iterating over row groups. To determine the group-ordering used by data.table, the best I could come up with is doing something like

```
grouping <- split(
  seq_len(nrow(tbl)),
  tbl[, list(GroupIndex = rep(.GRP, .N)), by = group_by][["GroupIndex"]]
)
```